# Consider $\mathsf{A,B,C},$ $\dots$ in a sans serif font. Each of these gives a graph in the plane. Sort these into homeomorphism classes.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Problem:

Show that homeomorphism is an equivalence relation on topological spaces. Now consider the capital letters of the alphabet $\mathsf{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z},$ in a sans serif font. Each of these gives a graph in the plane. Sort these into homeomorphism classes. (The partition may depend on the font! In particular, $\mathsf{K}$ can be tricky.)

---

What I got so far:

$\mathsf{C\cong G\cong I \cong J \cong L \cong U \cong V \cong Z}$

They are not closed curves and can be curved and bent to one another.

$\mathsf{D\cong O}$

Closed curves that can easily be bent to one another.

$\mathsf{C \ncong O}$ since removing a point in $\mathsf{C}$ makes it disconnected while $\mathsf{O}$ stays connected.

$\mathsf{E\ncong O}$ for the same reason.

$\mathsf{E\cong F}$

The standing line on $\mathsf{E}$ can be shrunk and the bottom line rotating and shrinking to make the straight standing line for $\mathsf{F}$. And the same reverse process for $\mathsf{F}$, which are homeomorphisms.

$\mathsf{K\cong X}$, this is easy to see.

and $\mathsf{K \ncong H}$ since deleting a point in $K$ gives 4 components but not in $H$.

I don't see any congruent letters for $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{H,R}$, so I think each is alone.

$\mathsf{P\cong Q}$ is clear.

$\mathsf{E\cong F\cong T \cong Y}$ as well.

$\mathsf{M\cong N\cong W}$ is also easy to see.

Is this correct, I would appreciate any corrections.

Comment: I can see why you found the question a bit surprising. It is asking you to think of the shape of each letter as a subspace of the plane, so that O is a circle, I is a line segment and the other letters are a bit more complicated.

Comment: There are two reasonable interpretations of this question: the letters have zero thickness (so that $\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are not homeomorphic), and the letters have finite thickness (so that the same two letters _are_ homeomorphic). But the remarks in parentheses ("in particular, $\mathsf{K}$ can be tricky") make it clear that the first interpretation is intended: depending on the font, $\mathsf{K}$ can be homeomorphic to $\mathsf{X}$ or $\mathsf{H}$, but not both.

Comment: @TonyK what do you mean by thickness? I don't understand what that is.

Comment: Tony is talking about the difference between painting the letters with a broad brush (so that letters are made up with thick lines and removing a point from the letter I will not disconnect it) as opposed to drawing them with an idealised pencil (so that the lines that make up the letter have zero width and removing the centre of an X will give four disconnected components).

Comment: To see why $\mathsf{E}\not\cong\mathsf{C}$, note that $\mathsf{E}$ has a point whose removal leaves a space with $3$ components, and $\mathsf{C}$ does not.

Comment: I’m showing serifs on your capital I, as displayed in your answer. I think your placement of “I” is correct, even though it doesn’t show correctly here.

Answer (score 3):

Homeomorphisms allow twisting and bending, but not (permanent) cuts. You can think of connectedness here to decide when two letters are *not* homeomorphic (e.g., remove one point from each letter, etc.). I won't do everything here as I think that this exercise is very important to get a feeling for these things, but here's some examples:

$${\sf C}\cong {\sf I} \cong {\sf V}, \quad {\sf D} \cong {\sf O}, \quad {\sf A}\not\cong {\sf O}, \quad {\sf L}\not\cong {\sf D}.$$

This classification can be also done thinking of homotopy classes instead of homeomorphism classes. I don't think it helps trying to write explicit homeomorphisms here. I mean, what are you going to do, parametrize the letter? The best we can gain here is intuition.

I refer you to the first chapter of [A First Course in Algebraic Topology - Czes Kosniowski](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521298644). It is a very nice book and may help you get this.

Comment: Our display fonts seem to differ: For me, the sans serif I in your answer is barred and so is not homeomorphic to $C$: Removing any nonendpoint from $C$ leaves a space with two components, removing the intersection of the bar from the vertical stroke in my I leaves one with three.

Comment: I used `{\sf I}`. Maybe it's something about the browser?

Comment: Perhaps, but the issue occurs for me in both Chrome and Safari (f.w.i.w., I'm using OS X).

Comment: Anyway, I mention it not to complain about your very good answer (+1, b.t.w.) but rather to alert the reader to this issue.

Comment: @IvoTerek I tried to complete the exercise following your suggestions, but got stuck along the way. I've written my work so far, can you help me out?

Comment: Everything you got so far seems correct. Good job. Let's join homeomorphic letters in sets. We can use the $\not\cong$'s there to find out which sets do not intersect. So far we have: $$\{  {\sf C,G,I,J,L,U,V,Z} \}, \qquad \{{\sf D, O}\}$$

Comment: Think a bit more. We have things like ${\sf M}\cong {\sf N} \cong {\sf I}$, so we have a bigger set: $$\{  {\sf C,G,I,J,L,U,V,Z,M,N} \}, $$and ${\sf A}\cong {\sf R}$, ${\sf P}\not\cong {\sf O}$, etc.

Comment: Why do we get $\mathsf{M\cong I}$? Take the top middle point in I then we get three components, but we never get three by taking any point out in M. And also taking the middle point in R out we get three components, but not in A...

Comment: We get ${\sf M}\cong {\sf I}$ in the same way you got ${\sf E} \cong {\sf F}$.

Comment: @IvoTerek I don't understand it. If I take out the point on the middle top of $\mathsf{I}$, I get three components right? But taking any point out in $\mathsf{M}$, I can get at most two components.

Comment: I saying that ${\sf M} \cong {\sf I}$, **not** that ${\sf M}\not\cong {\sf I}$. Just take ${\sf M}$ and "straighten" it up.

Comment: Ivo Terek: "point in the **middle** top of $\sf I$" suggests `{\sf I}` $\sf I$ looks like serif `{\rm I}` $\rm I$ for @takecare as mentioned by Travis. The homeomorphism class obviously depends on how that letter is typeset. (This must be some MathJax issue/feature. There are indeed sans-serif fonts that have "bars" on "$\sf I$". For me $\sf I$ looks like a straight line "|" - like it's supposed to.) To prevent confusion it might be a good idea to include a [picture of the typeface](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OXYni.png) we are talking about in the question. ("...OXYnim.png" to scale pic.)

Comment: @Piwi Ah, yes! If the letter I have the bars, then it is not homeomorphic to M, and OP's argument is correct. I think the letters are showing up the same for us, I was thinking of the letter I as the one in the image you linked.